# Developer Console Search in Files

Tags: developer-console

Is there a way to get the developer console to return results from Visualforce Components when using the Edit -> Search in Files feature?
I get VF pages, and Apex Classes, but not VF Components.

Comment: Not sure about the console on components, but I can suggest for global code search (and editor) I use SublimeText3 with MavensMate.   The effort in setting it up (not much) is well worth it.  ctrl+shift+f performs a lightning fast search through all code resources, clicking on results jumps you to that file at that line.  Then there is Eclipse with the force.com IDE, and many other IDE's which have the same feature.... but mavensmate is the best ;) - my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use something like the Chrome developer tools when running the "Search in Files" functionality you will see the REST API call going out to the web services.

> https://na2.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/search/?q=FIND%20%7BFoo%7D%20IN%20ALL%20FIELDS%20RETURNING%20ApexClass(id%2C%20name%2C%20namespaceprefix%2C%20body)%2C%20ApexTrigger(id%2C%20name%2C%20namespaceprefix%2C%20body)%2C%20ApexPage(id%2C%20name%2C%20namespaceprefix%2C%20markup)%2C%20ApexComponent(id%2C%20name%2C%20namespaceprefix%2C%20markup)&_=1431996616461

After URL decoding the SOSL query is:

> FIND {Foo} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(id, name, namespaceprefix, body), ApexTrigger(id, name, namespaceprefix, body), ApexPage(id, name, namespaceprefix, markup), ApexComponent(id, name, namespaceprefix, markup)

ApexComponent is labelled "Visualforce Component", so in theory it should be searching the VF components as well.

I confirmed that it can indeed find known content in a VF Component.
[image]

However, it was a bit hit and miss about what it would actually find. Other terms that I know appear in the markup didn't come back in the results.

As Mike commented, pulling down the metadata and then searching it locally with the tool of your choice may be the best option.

Comment: This is great, since we can search an entire phrase by adding double quotes and fire the sosl that you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

You can add Google Chrome Extension **Salesforce Advanced Code Searcher**.It searches Apex Classes,VF Pages,Visualforce Components,Apex Triggers.

[image]

Here is the Chrome Extension [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

FYI. I am not affiliated with above chrome extension

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with that product? It's fine if you do or do not. However, if you do, please state so in your answer.